# How to compare a certain value of a character array in a specific index to another character array in a specific index

Tags: arrays, loops, indexing, char, compare

I'm having trouble comparing two character arrays. We are asked to make a program that will get the common and combine characters using 2 arrays. The combine function will combine all the inputs in the array and if there are common letters, the function will only display the letter once.
Example:

```
q w e r r
e r t y u
Output: q w e r t y u
```

while the common function will only display the common characters
Example:

```
q w e r r
e r t y u
Output: e r
```

I need looping statements and dynamic allocations specifically malloc. If there is no need to use boolean data type then pls don't use. Use if otherwise.

The prototypes of the two functions are:

```
char*comb(char*,char*) //For combine method
char*comm(char*,char*) //For common method
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the first array is `Array1` and the second one is `Array2`.

In order to create the Combine function, you should create a third array named `Array3`.

```
public void Combine()
{
    bool exist = false;
    for (int i=0; i<Array1.lengh; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<Array3.lengh; j++)
        {
            if (Array[i] != Array[j])
                exist = false;
            else {
                exist = true;
                break;
            }
         }
         if (!exist)
         {
              Array3.add(Array1[i]);
              // output Array1[i] depends on the program you're using
         }
    }
}
```

See the logic how it should be and try to create `Common` function.

Comment: what does "bool exist = false" mean?

Comment: `bool` is a type like `int` or `string`.... `bool` only can take two variables: `true` or `false`. Here I'm testing if the value exists, then i set exist to true, if not, i set it to false, so if it does not exist, it will be added to Array3 and will be outputted.

Comment: ohh ok i get the concept. Thnx. Can you make another version of this funtion without using boolean data types?

Comment: just the same program. We are required to use malloc function my func prototypes are also char*comb(char*,char*) and char*comm(char*,char*)

Comment: Since you have all these requirements, edit your question and all the info so you will get a correct answer without wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the combine function, you can pass char arrays as string parameters to the function as following

```
combine("qwerr", "ertyu");     // returns "qwertyu"
function combine() {
  var jString, jArr, cArr;

  jString = "";
  cArr = [];

  for (var i = 0, ii = arguments.length; i < ii; i++) {
    jString += arguments[i];
  }

  jArr = jString.split("");

  cArr.push(jArr[0]);

  for (var j = 0, jj = jArr.length; j < jj; j++) {
    if (test(j)) {
      cArr.push(jArr[j]);
    }
  }

  function test(j) {
    var x = true;
    for (var k = 0, kk = cArr.length; k < kk; k++) {
      if (cArr[k] == jArr[j]) {
        x = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return x;
  }

  return cArr.join("");
}
```

Function for common array can be created using same concept.